Why am I getting a different answer when I use different methods?
I just graduated high school and was doing some math in my spare time, but I can't seem to figure out why when I integrate this particular integral,
$I = \int{\frac{x}{3-x}}dx$
I get different answers.
My method:
$\ { u = 3 - x} $
$\ { \frac{du}{dx} = -1} $
Therefore:
$\ { I = -\int{\frac{3-u}{u}}du = u - 3ln(u) + C} $
So my result becomes:
$\ I = 3 - x - 3ln(3 - x) + C $
What I don't understand is: when I solved this using Wolfram Alpha I got this answer, where they simply just divided the 2 polynomials, and reaching the answer:
$\ {I = -x - 3ln(3-x) + C} $
I'm trying to understand why I reach a different answer, when I do the integral using u-sub. Please be gentle with me, I am nowhere near as decorated as the mathematicians here, and I'm just trying to find my way around, so I can hopefully be like you guys one day. Thank you in advance!

What definition of indefinite integral do you know?

Indefinite integrals are defined up to a constant of integration, hence $C_{you} + 3 = C_{Wolfram}$ in the present case.

$3+C$ and $C$ are all constants, so you can write $3+C:=C$.

Please do not answer the question in the comments, @Abezhiko.

The same goes to you, @BoweiTang.

There exists infinitely many functions $F(x)$ such that $F'(x)=\frac{x}{x-3}.$ The important thing is that all such functions $F$ are on  the form $$F(x)=-x-3\ln |3-x|+C,$$ where $C$ is a constant. You have obtained such two functions $F$, the first one $$F_1(x)=-x-3\ln |3-x|+C_1,$$ and $$F_2(x)=3-x-3\ln|3-x|+C_2.$$ Both are solutions and the only difference is that $C_1=3+C_2.$ Also don't forget the absolute value on $\ln |3-x|$, since we want to have the logarithm well defined

Thank you very much! This makes a lot of sense. I guess I need to really just focus on what an indefinite integral really is. This was very helpful. Thank you all for being very kind.

Yeah! Is important to know the basics. You are welcome :)

No worries!  We (not just decorated, but casual mathematicians like myself :-) ) are here to help people who make the effort to ask the questions and ask where they went wrong - your question and how it's presented is a perfect case of that (although there may be times where your question was answered elsewhere, and the question you asked may be closed).
